# How to send an email from my application using email application?

Tags: android, email, mobile

How to send an email from my application using email application?

I am having the one scenario like send email to particular mail id(`info@jeltech.com`). In my application while clicking the link it should call email application and then need to pass above mail id to in "To" box (after login) .

Is there any solution for this issue?

Regards,
Jeyavel N

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code to launch the action `ACTION_SENDTO` in a new activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, 
                           Uri.fromParts("mailto", "test@test.com", null));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the html syntax and embed a html link into your application.

I'm not 100% sure it will work with android but I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.

[See the example here](http://www.pageresource.com/html/mail.htm)

Hope this helps
Pete